# Issue in Executing a batch script during -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError event

Tags: powershell, scripting, out-of-memory

I have written a power shell script in my Win 2008 server, to execute the below mentioned 4 steps whenever an OutOfMemoryError occurs in the system.

1. Email users that the applications is going to be restarted.
2. stop the app service
3. clear cache and tmp files
4. start the service
5. email users that the service is started

The Script is given below and it is working like a gem when executed manually. I have added the below .ps1 script in a .bat file and updated the registry entry as

***-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="D:\Support\UWD_OOM_restart.bat"***

***Issue***: Whenever an OOM error occurs, the batch script invokes the power shell script, but only the first 3 steps are getting executed automatically. The last 2 steps( starting the service and emailing end users are not getting executed automatically). Need some assistance in this case

Power shell script:

```
$hostname =  'XXXXXX'
$smtpServer = 'xxxxxxxx' 
$from = "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com" 
$recipients = 'xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com'
$Subject = "Restarting Apps - UWD Service on $hostname due to Java OUT OF MEMORY ERROR" 
$body = "This is an automated message to confirm that the UWD service on xxxxxxxx server is about to be restarted, as the application has encountered Java out of memory error and went to unresponsive state. Kindly ignore any alerts for the next 10 minutes from this service." 


Send-MailMessage -To $recipients -Subject $Subject -Body $body -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpServer 


# Stop service

$service = 'xxxxxxxx" 

    Stop-Service -name $service -Verbose 

    do { 
        Start-sleep -s 5 
        }  
        until ((get-service $service).Status -eq 'Stopped') 
# Folder delete
rm -r -fo 'D:\xxxxxxx\cache'
rm -r -fo 'D:\xxxxxxx\tmp'

# Start service 

    start-Service -name $service -Verbose 

do { 
    Start-sleep -s 5 
    }  
        until ((get-service $service).Status -eq 'Running') 


# Send confirmation that service has restarted successfully 

$Subject = "UWD Service Restarted Successfully on $hostname" 
$body = "This mail confirms that the UWD application service on $hostname is now running. 
Application Team, Kindly smoke test your application and inform xxxxxx for any issues." 

Start-Sleep -s 5 

Send-MailMessage -To $recipients -Subject $Subject -Body $body -From $from -SmtpServer $smtpServer
```

Comment: What state is the service in? My initial thought would be that it is in a Starting or Stopping state. You can wrap the service actions in a `try{}` `catch{}` and output it to a txt file for logging. This might give you a place to start.

Comment: The service is in "STOPPED" state

Comment: Is the last `Send-MailMessage` is being sent?

Comment: Nope...Only the fisrt send mail message is gettng executed and mail is sent out successfully...then the app service is getting stopped, then the cache 7 tmp files are getting deleted. After these 3 steps, the 4th step (app service startup) and the 5th step Send-mailMessage are not getting executed automatically.

Comment: Wrap the remainder of your script (starting at `Start-Service`) `try{Start-Service -name $Service -verbose "Service Starting" | Add-Content C:\Log.txt } catch{$_ | Add-Content C:\log.txt}`

Comment: Im getting a log output as "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Service Starting'. " while doing so. Now trying to get that fixed.

Comment: `"Service Starting" | Add-Content C:\Log.txt` should be on a new line